# Indexing a group of Sitecore subitems as their parent item

Tags: c#, indexing, sitecore, sitecore7

In my content tree, I have items that contains sub items. The sub items are where the content for the parent item are.

E.g.

```
Article container   <---- only this item is navigable to the user
    |
    |- Text block = "foo foo foo foo"
    |- Image      = "foo.jpg"
    |- Text block = "foo foo foo"
```

When the user navigates my website, they will never find a link to any of the sub items. They will only ever get to the url for "Article container", which has a presentation such that all of the sub items are displayed on the page.

In a regular indexing scenario, all 3 sub items would match the query ***"foo"*** and be returned in the results. I want to create a Sitecore 7 index purely for website search which will return the **parent** item ("Article container") for a search query for the term ***"foo"***. I don't want any of the sub items to be returned in the query results.

- Is this possible to do with some combination of computed fields,
  inbound or outbound index filters (or something else I haven't heard
  about)?
- Or will I have to parse the output and resolve the parent
  item before displaying it to the user?

***EDIT***

@martindavies' answer is good, but I was wondering if there's a way to do the indexing "upstream" where you index the child item and store it's content against the parent item in the index, rather than "downstream" where you index the parent and store all child content in the parent's index entry. The reason for this is so that any edits to the child items will be re-indexed automatically without having to manually trigger a re-index of the parent article.

Answer (score 5):

eYou could create a computed field called 'childitemcontent' that does the following during the indexing process:

- Is the item being indexed an article?
- if it is, loop through each child item
- for each child item, loop through the fields and add the content to the computed field

Here's a good article to get you started:

[SITECORE 7: COMPUTED INDEX FIELDS](http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/03/Sitecore-7-Computed-Index-Fields.aspx)

I actually asked something very similar a while back (pre Sitecore 7) and was directed to a video which was quite helpful:

[Sitecore - Indexing data from presentation components with non-context datasources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17132504/sitecore-indexing-data-from-presentation-components-with-non-context-datasourc)

The good thing about that approach is that it doesn't rely on the referenced items being children of the page item. (FWIW I'm not a fan of storing page content items under a page. I prefer to keep them outside the content tree).

Comment: Thanks @martindavies, I was wondering if there's also another way... This method is a "down-stream" approach (parent to child) where you index the parent and in doing so gather data from its children. If possible, I'd like an "up-stream" approach where you index the child and attribute it to it's parent. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: I think you would still need to use my down-stream approach, but in addition you need a way to convert a request to index the child item into one that indexes the parent (e.g. by checking to see if the parent of the requested item is an article). It's getting outside of my experience, but I think you might be able to achieve this with a custom analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the easiest way to achieve this is to have all of your page items inherit from a common base template, and then to create an index that only includes items that inherit from said base template.

Think about Sitecore from a higher level, i.e. don't think about indexing based on field values (which can always be changed), but rather think about indexing based on the type of item that you want.

**Update**

*Note: In my original answer (above), I slightly misunderstood the goal you were trying to achieve with the index. The above would hold true if you are looking to just index the items representing the pages that you would go to.*

IMHO, for your situation the best thing to do would be to actually run the index as you normally would (which would index the child items as hitting points) but to then use URL Rewriting/a custom Rewrite Processor to direct all requests to the children of an article item to the article item instead.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, but I'm not clear on how you would group together the sub-items to represent a single article. Surely the index you describe would still just return a hit pointing to the sub-item?

Comment: No, the idea is that the page items are the actual articles (parents) and the other items (children) are just some other data items that does not inherit from your Base Page template. As such, only the parent items would be included in the index.

Comment: If only the parent items are in the index, then none of the content of the child items would be in the index, thus defeating the purpose of said index. I need to be able to search for the field contents of all child items and return the parent item as the result.

Comment: @theyetiman - I misunderstood your post at first. I have updated my answer to better fit the situation you were describing

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I suppose that is a solution, but the problem is that I want to use the index hits as search results to display to the user. In other words, I want to show a list of matching articles (not article children) on a page. Using a rewrite processor or custom item resolver would work for a link pointing to a child item, but I don't want to generate that link in the first place. I just want to generate the link to the parent item. Ideally I want the indexing to do all this without post-processing the results. It looks like @martindavies answer might be my only option.

Comment: Not a problem - that's completely understandable. I will leave my solution up in case it helps others with a slightly different goal. Good luck and happy coding! :)