# c# Sitecore search: show where components are used

Tags: c#, search, lucene, sitecore

I've implemented a simple search functionality in Sitecore by writing the following:

```
string searchStr = Server.UrlDecode(WebUtil.GetQueryString("searchStr"));

FullTextQuery query = new FullTextQuery(searchStr);
SearchHits hits = indexSearchContext.Search(query, int.MaxValue);
SearchResultCollection results = hits.FetchResults(0, 100);
```

This correctly gets all occurrences of the searchStr. I then loop through the results and show them:

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Item hit = result.GetObject<Item>();
    if (hit != null)
    {
        string hitText = GenerateHitText(hit);
        LiteralControl hitControl = new LiteralControl(hitText);
        pnResultsPanel.Controls.Add(hitControl);
     }
}
```

The issue is that I have text box components on pages and when searching it will return those as well. I don't want users to see components when searching, I only want them to see pages where that component is used. I'm thinking it would look a bit like this:

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Item hit = result.GetObject<Item>();
    if (hit != null)
    {
        if (//hit is a component) 
        {
            foreach (//page where hit (the component) is placed) 
            {
                //Do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me write something that would achieve that?
Thanks.

Comment: You may want to change your approach - instead of indexing components datasources, index all the components content inside the `_content` field of the page. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17132504/157833

Comment: Okay, I tried to follow your link. I implemented VisualizationField.cs, but when I tried to insert <dynamicFields hint="raw:AddDynamicFields"> in the Web.config inside the index, it gives me a runtime error "Could not find add method: AddDynamicFields (type: Sitecore.Search.Crawlers.DatabaseCrawler)". Do I need to add anything else?

Comment: One of the things that I have been playing with lately is adding an `html` field to the document of all my page items as a computed index field that holds the full-text html of the page.

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel: Be careful with full HTML indexing, you'll be pulling in things like header/footer wchih may not actually want to search on... take a look at [this Lucene crawler](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/E/eFocus_Lucene_webcrawler_and_search_module.aspx), esp the documentation/configuration section to see one way of handling this.

Comment: @jammykam: I totally agree. For my experiements, I have mostly been playing around with conditions in my controller actions (based on Rendering parameters) to determine whether or not a rendering should be indexed. I'm not a huge fan of this solution, and would prefer to go the route of creating a separate Device for my indexing. The only issue, then, is making sure that the content author adds to the page and wants indexed are also added to the new device. I haven't had time to jump into that one yet, though

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the components items as component only (i.e. they are not browseable by themselves) it should be fairly straightforward I think:

```
foreach (var result in results)
{
    Item hit = result.GetObject<Item>();
    if (hit != null)
    {
        // Potentially you need to just check the __Renderings or
        // __FinalRenderings field here instead
        if (hit.Visualization.Layout == null) 
        {
            foreach (Sitecore.Globals.LinkDatabase.GetReferrers(item)) 
            {
                //Do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using component items as regular pages too it might be a bit more complicated.

Comment: Just having seen Marek's comment, that might be the better option - I think that would perform better than the above - especially at scale.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement a full content search, Lucene might be not your best option. Although what you are asking is possible if you start implementing it, you might find some issues.

Best way is to include the content in the index (see Mareks comment). But analyze your solution before starting, as problems could arise when updating content.

The problem is that there sometimes are cases where not all components are immediately related to the page (through a datasource) - otherwise you can use the link database, ComputedFields, ... But unfortunately that is not always the case. For example, when you have a rendering that gets a datasource which is actually the parent of the items you are really displaying... Also consider that this might be not an issue now, but it could limit you in future development as well.

For content updates: if your component content gets changed, your search needs to know. This can be a problem if your content is embedded in the index (which is the fastest way). You need a solution to update the right items, and if they are not truly linked that is not so easy.

There are of course always some other options - rebuilding your index once every day for example.

So it all depends on your solution: structure, amount of data, ... (and don't consider just the 'now' but also think ahead for the future).